# Composer version conflit in laravel project

Tags: laravel, composer-php

When I did the composer update a problem showed like it's shown below could you give me how to choose version

```
  Problem 1
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 5.0.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.0.0].
    - nesbot/carbon 1.39 requires symfony/translation ^4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/translation[4.0.x-dev, 4.1.x-dev, 4.2.x-dev, 4.3.x-dev, 4.4.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/translation[4.0.x-dev, 2.6.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/translation[4.1.x-dev, 2.6.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/translation[4.2.x-dev, 2.6.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/translation[4.3.x-dev, 2.6.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/translation[4.4.x-dev, 2.6.x-dev].
    - laravel/framework v5.0.0 requires nesbot/carbon ~1.0 -> satisfiable by nesbot/carbon[1.39].
    - Installation request for symfony/translation 2.6.x-dev -> satisfiable by symfony/translation[2.6.x-dev].
```

Comment: Can you share your `composer.json` file also?

Comment: this error due to the carbon version you trying to install. you are trying to install laters carbon version on laravel 5.0. therefor you can try `composer require nesbot/carbon:1.0` note that I have specified carbon package version here.

Answer (score 0):

In your composer.json file you are propably requiring symfony/translation in version 2.6.
Update symfony/translation to ^4.0 and you should be good to go

Comment: the problem is laravel 5.0 requires symfony/translation 2.6 and carbon requires ^4.0

Comment: ok - so either you can't use this carbon version or you have to update laravel...